# Are point estimators and set estimators the same thing?

Tags: terminology, estimators

My professor defined a point estimator as

> A mathematical rule that maps a random sample $\lbrace x_i \rbrace_{i=1}^n$ into a 'best guess' at the parameter $\theta$

I am confused about what distinguishes a point estimator from a set estimator.

Can't a point belong to a set? Why is there a distinction between the two if point estimators are actually set estimators?

Comment: Can you also provide the definition of set estimator you are using?

Comment: We weren't given one :(

Comment: in fact, my professor didn't even know the word set estimator

Comment: So if you do not know what is the set estimator what kind of answer do you expect? Point estimator is a quite often used term, and its definition is usually a variant of the definition given by your professor. However set estimator is not a widely used term and can mean different things, that is why your professor was unaware of it.

Comment: The alternative category is interval estimates,  which typically provide you a probability of lying within the given interval. So estimate of population mean is 9, vs population mean has 95% probability of lying between 8.5 and 12

Comment: What is the difference between an interval estimator and set estimator?